# Relacionamento 1x1(ou não)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, relacionamento

Tenho 2 entidades:

ItemPedido e Produto...

Usando o fluent API como digo para minha entidade ItemPedido que ela tem um Produto?

Obs: A entidade produto não pode ter dependências, apesar de que 1 produto pode esta em vários itemPedido eu não quero que ela dependa de um itemPedido para existir...

**Classe Produto:**

```
namespace DTO
{
    public class ProdutoDTO
    {
        public int produtoID { get; set; }
        public int codigo { get; set; }
        public string descricao { get; set; }
        public decimal preco { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Classe ItemPedido:**

```
namespace DTO
{
    public class ItemPedidoDTO
    {
        public int itemPedidoID { get; set; }
        public int quantidade { get; set; }
        public int porcentagemDesconto { get; set; }

        public int produdoID { get; set; }
        public virtual ProdutoDTO produto { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: E onde está o código?

Comment: Editei e os coloquei.

Comment: Certo, não vejo nenhuma dependência de `ProdutoDTO` com `ItemPedidoDTO`, qual é a sua dúvida? Não existe uma terceira "entidade" `PedidoDTO`, que armazenará os `ItemPedidoDTO`? Ps.: o atributo `preco` deve ficar na `ItemPedidoDTO`, caso contrário se você alterar o preço de um produto, vai mudar o valor em todos os seus pedidos já realizados.

Comment: Sim existe a entidade PedidoDTO, eu que retirei do código o pedidoID e virtual pedido achando que não precisava mostrar já que não falei dela... nossa bem observado, nem notei a questão do preço, vlw! Minha duvida é: "o que eu escrevo com Fluent API na configuração do Entity Framework especifica da classe para dizer que ItemPedido tem um Produto, mas o Produto não tem dependência?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar o seguinte código para mapear o relacionamento unidirecional:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<ItemPedidoDTO>().HasRequired(i => i.produto).WithMany();
```

- **HasRequired** configura o relacionamento para produto como obrigatório
- **WithMany()** configura o relacionamento para ser obrigatorio:muitos sem propriedade de navegação do lado muitos

Se inglês for tranquilo para você, considere dar uma lida nesse link https://stackoverflow.com/a/20909649/2721661